# use array to add listener in google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a question about using array to add listener to marker in google map api. It seems we cannot directly use an iteration to add the listener but could call a function to do that. I search the internet and found that it's a scope problem. But I don't understand what's the reason. Any one can give me a clear explaination? Thanks!

```
works version
function updateM(m) {
google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,m);
  });
}
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
marker[i].setMap(map);
updateM(marker[i]);
}

and 

do not work version
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
marker[i].setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker[i]);
  });
}


}
```

Comment: It's explained here: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm but this is not a question for SO.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there is no `block` scope, only `function scope` exists. So by wrapping the `addListners` code in a new function, you ensure that the value of `"i"` remains as you intended.